# How to make Python script executed in background?

Tags: php, python, subprocess

Actually, the question in the topic title.

You need to call from PHP Python script, but do not wait for his answer.

How can this be done correctly?

Comment: Did you try to find out how to execute a program in general without waiting for it to complete the execution? You could start from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @mishu Php waiting for execution exec()! I need a script running in the background completely!

Comment: If you really read the page you will find what you need. If you are too busy you can look around this statement: `in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume, from your PHP program, you want to run a Python script in background.

This is a relevant part from the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php:
If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Try something like this:

```
system("python myscript.py myargs > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```